# Why does this Powershell Script create converted images OUTSIDE the Rootfolder?

Tags: powershell, imagemagick, powershell-5.0

The following Powershell script is supposed to process all designated images INSIDE the specified Rootfolder.   Some of the renamed output images are generated OUTSIDE the Rootfolder.  Any Powershell gurus have any idea why?
How can I output files only in the Rootfolder and not OUTSIDE the Rootfolder?

```
# This script requires ImageMagick
# Configuration
# Enter the full path of the folder that contains the images
$Rootfolder = "C:\temp\rktest"


$Recursive=$true
# Change these if necessary
$fileExtensions = "*.png"
$fileNameSuffix = "_resized" # the text to be appended to the output filename to indicate that it has been modified

$files = $null;
$fileCount = 0

# Check if the root folder is a valid folder. If not, try again.
if ((Test-Path $RootFolder -PathType 'Container') -eq $false) {
    Write-Host "'$RootFolder' doesn't seem to be a valid folder. Please try again" -ForegroundColor Red
    break
}

# Get all image files in the folder
if ($Recursive) {
    $files = gci $RootFolder -Filter $fileExtensions -File -Recurse
} 

# If there are no image files found, write out a message and quit
if ($files.Count -lt 1) {
    Write-Host "No image files with extension '$fileExtensions' were found in the folder '$RootFolder'" -ForegroundColor Red
    break
}

# Loop through each of the files and process it
foreach ($image in $files) {
    $newFilename = $image.DirectoryName + " " + $image.BaseName + $fileNameSuffix + $image.Extension
    $imageFullname = $image.FullName

    write-host "Processing image: $imageFullname" -ForegroundColor Green
#This line contains the ImageMagick commands
    & convert.exe $image.FullName -resize 50% $newFilename

    $fileCount++
}

Write-Host "$fileCount images processed" -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

Comment: What do you mean with `OUTSIDE`?

Comment: You're not showing the complete script.

Comment: Gerald - I am showing the complete script - what do you see is missing?

Comment: I see break commands. They are meant to exit a loop but are not inside a loop.  I see a variable $Recursive that is never set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space between directory and filename, put a backslash

```
$newFilename = $image.DirectoryName + "\" + $image.BaseName + $fileNameSuffix + $image.Extension
```

Comment: That's IMO contrary to the OPs intention.

Comment: Gerald - please explain the purpose of a backslash instead of a space.

Comment: The purpose is to put the file in the directory specified by DirectoryName.  Don't you know the meaning of the backslashes as in "C:\temp\rktest" ???

Comment: Gerald - Thanks for the explanation.  Your suggestion to change the newFilename line from the space between directory and filename to a backslash FIXED the problem.  The script now creates all OUTPUT files in the same subfolder as the SOURCE images.

Comment: In that case, you could perhaps accept my answer?

Comment: @LotPings, thanks for showing me the errors of my ways.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right the resized images should be placed in
`$RootFolder` but retain the subfolder names as part of the filename, space separated.

The following script results in this sample tree:

```
> tree /F
C:.
└───temp
    └───rktest
        │   Image.png
        │   Image_resized.png
        │   SubDirL1 Image_resized.png
        │   SubDirL1 SubDirL2 Image_resized.png
        │
        └───SubDirL1
            │   Image.png
            │
            └───SubDirL2
                    Image.png
```

It creates a calculated property `RelPAth` with a select, adding it to the $file collection.
This is done by first removing the RootFolder from FullName and replacing any remaining path separators `\` with spaces.

When building the new file name the extension is replaced with suffix+extension.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\06\02\SU_1327985.ps1
# This script requires ImageMagick
# Configuration
# Enter the full path of the folder that contains the images
$Rootfolder = "C:\temp\rktest"

$Recursive=$true
# Change these if necessary
$fileExtensions = "*.png"
$fileNameSuffix = "_resized" # the text to be appended to the output filename to indicate that it has been modified

$files = $null;
$fileCount = 0

# Check if the root folder is a valid folder. If not, try again.
if ((Test-Path $RootFolder -PathType 'Container') -eq $false) {
    Write-Host "'$RootFolder' doesn't seem to be a valid folder. Please try again" -ForegroundColor Red
    break
}

# Get all image files in the folder
if ($Recursive) {
    $files = gci $RootFolder -Filter $fileExtensions -File -Recurse |
      select *,@{n='RelPath';e={ ($_.FullName.Replace($RootFolder+"\",'')).Replace('\',' ') }}
} 

# If there are no image files found, write out a message and quit
if ($files.Count -lt 1) {
    Write-Host "No image files with extension '$fileExtensions' were found in the folder '$RootFolder'" -ForegroundColor Red
    break
}

# Loop through each of the files and process it
foreach ($image in $files) {
    $newFilename = Join-Path $RootFolder ($image.RelPath.Replace($image.Extension,($fileNameSuffix+$image.Extension)))
    write-host "Processing image: $($image.Fullname)" -ForegroundColor Green
    #This line contains the ImageMagick commands
    & magick convert $image.FullName -resize 50% $newFilename

    $fileCount++
}

Write-Host "$fileCount images processed" -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

Replaced convert.exe with `magick convert` due to my ImageMagick version.

Comment: Sorry I can't follow: as my sample tree shows all files in $RootFolder **and** in subdirs were processed. As long as the `-Recurse` parameter in the gci command is present it should process all subdirs.

Comment: I **did** ask what you mean with OUTSIDE and got no answer. I assumed it was your intention to place them all in $RootFolder and contain the folder name prepended in the file name - thats what the code does now.

Comment: Not toplevel that would be root. You should have better explained where you want them first place.

Comment: LotPings - Thank you for your instructions.  Your script works perfectly for placing the OUTPUT files in the TOP level folder.  I am sorry if my question made it difficult to understand what I wanted - but between you and Gerald - I now have a script that can create ALL output files in the TOP folder and a script that can create ALL output files in the same subfolder as the source images.